# Bootstrap 3 Carousel: CSS3 slider transitions don't work in older IE -- what to do?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I was shocked to discover that the default Carousel in Bootstrap 3 does not support CSS3 slider transition animations in older IE browsers (6, 7, 8, 9). When I check the git repository of bootstrap for this I found several commits made saying it has been fixed, but some no longer support the fixes and others have stopped production. I'm confused on which/what to use to fix my Carousel transition in IE. Anyone know what is the best version to use? My customer requires IE8 as the primary browser, so need to get the default BS3 carousel to slide nicely.

Comment: This is what I'm expecting: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/3052 . Is this the recommended fix?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Bootstrap [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), it's clearly mentioned as

> **Transition animations not supported in Internet Explorer 8 & 9**
>
> Bootstrap exclusively uses CSS3 for its animations, but Internet Explorer 8 & 9 don't support the necessary CSS properties. Thus, there are no slide transition animations when using these browsers. We have intentionally decided not to include jQuery-based fallbacks for the transitions.

So, if you're familiar with jquery, you can add fallback as mentioned by redshift. Otherwise, you can use any other carousels such as http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ which is responsive which has lot of customization options, or http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified etc which are working fine even in ie7 also. Choice is yours.

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your html:-

```
        <!--[if lte IE 9]>       
            <script src="_includes/js/ie-bootstrap-carousel.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to use a different version of the bootstrap file here otherwise this answer is a bit ambiguous. The code above will load this in ie browsers less than 9. You also need to make sure it wont load the regular js is the other issue here.